# Google maps not completely rendering in IE8

Tags: google-maps

See [screenshot](https://img.skitch.com/20110126-qghjtcmbd4gxx6m4jn5ncsu3fs.jpg). Chrome/Safari/Firefox work perfectly. In IE8, it goes to about a third of the way down and then is just gray for the rest of the page. The wacky thing is that as soon as I resize the page in any way, the rest of the tiles come in and it works great. I've attempted the "google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize')" fix, but that hasn't helped. Any advice would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Finally figured it out. You have to do the following, but also delay it by a bit for the map to finish loading. So lame.

> ```
> setTimeout('google.maps.event.trigger(gMap, "resize");gMap.setZoom(gMap.getZoom());', 300);
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Try calling 'map.checkResize()' after the map is supposed to have been drawn. I don't do much web development, but I remember a buddy of mine having the same issue recently and he fixed it by having IE call that method after drawing the map.

Hope this helps, if I misunderstood your question, I do apologize.

Comment: Looks like v3 of the Google Maps API doesn't have that function, but I tried something similar (google.maps.event.trigger(gMap, 'resize'); gMap.setZoom( gMap.getZoom() );) and still no luck :(

Answer (score 0):

please try this code after your initialize() OR loadMap() function.

> setTimeout("loadMap()",500);

and put this line at the end of initialize function.

> clearTimeout(0);

This may helpfull for you.